# Python Selenium:firefox headless option not working with Firefox 52.8.0 (32-bit)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-headless

I want to run firefox in headless mode on server but both options.add_argument("--headless") and options.set_headless(headless=True) are not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
print("Executing script")
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.set_headless(headless=True)
try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, 
    executable_path="/path-to-driver/geckodriver.exe");
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print(driver.page_source)
finally:
driver.quit()
print ("Script executed successfully")
```

I am using Python 3.6.5, Selenium 3.12.0 and firefox 52.8.0 (32-bit).

Comment: And....what is the actual error?

Comment: It works for me. I tried the same code you have just removing the try..finally blocks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode#Browser_support

Comment: @slackmart It is opening the GUI firefox browser. I want headless means no GUI invoked.

Comment: Update your fx version, check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: This version is running on prod server so updating version seems to be issue at present. Looking for any other options, if someone has it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any such issue in your code trails. However it seems there is a **version mismatch** within the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *Selenium 3.12.0* and *Firefox v52.8.0*.
- As per the following discussions:
- [Support headless flag on Linux](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356681)
- [Expand headless mode support for linux](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/d7121e5ad806)

The milestone for *Mozilla Headless Mode* was **Mozilla v55.0a1**

---

### Solution

Upgrading your *Mozilla Browser Client* to **Mozilla v55.0a1** or above will address your issue.